# numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided with Eigen

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen

How to implement the same functionality with Eigen which is done by numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided()?

https://pyprog.pro/indexing_routines/lib_stride_tricks_as_strided.html

Here is an example on Python I want to reproduce with Eigen:

```
y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, (6, 6), (24, 4))
y
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

Comment: This is just a reshape isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I wondering if there is something like that out of the box in eigen.

Comment: Give a look to [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) from the Eigen documentation.

Comment: With the development branch (or 3.4-alpha) you can use `.reshape()`: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialReshape.html. Btw, I have no idea what the `(24,4)` does in your example.